# How do I change Administrator to Super Administrator

Tags: admin

How does one change an Administrator to Super Administrator in cpanel for a Wordpress site?

I have gone into the databases and into wp-users, wp-usermeta, but still cannot figure out how it's done.

Context - a PHP developer who worked on the site changed the Super admin to Administrator and I need to set the person back to Super.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to grant that level of access on the user's profile page. I assume you have a mulitsite install of WordPress, otherwise there is no Superadmin role.

Comment: I do not have a multisite version of the site. I am trying set an Administrator to Super Administrator and that option you mentioned is not available in the profile page you mentioned - the highest is Administrator. I was told there is some way to do it on FTP and/or using cpanel?

Comment: If you don't have a multisite than the Administrator role is the highest role. This equals the role of Superadmin on a multisite. You are looking for something that is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What RST said. "SuperAdmins" are for network (multi-site) only. That user has ability to be the admin of all sub-sites.

"Admin" is the highest level for non-multi-site (non-network) sites.

(added as an answer to show that this question is answered by a comment to the question).